# Are there any barriers to implementing an ethereum node as a chrome or firefox extension?

Tags: nodes, light-clients, browsers

Is it possible to create a Firefox or Chrome extension which ran either a full node or light node?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be possible to create a light node. A full node is probably impossible. Your main limitation is storage space ([5Mb for some browsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage#Storage_size)). This page on the [light client protocol](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Light-client-protocol) specifically mentions extensions, though it's a year old. You would also not want to use too much CPU, as the user wouldn't thank you for running at a high CPU continuously.

Comment: I reworded my question to be phrased in the *positive* perspective which now makes the wording of your answer a little awkward.

Comment: And I've reworded my answer.